# Is there any way to make my qt window stay's always on top at specified position in kwin wayland

Tags: qml, qt6, wayland

I was working on a screen overlay application that can be used to draw anywhere on the screen. for that, I want to stay my window always on top of other Wayland windows. I've already managed to do that in X11 by using window flags `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint`. This flag also works on the gnome Wayland session. But this flag doesn't work on the plasma Wayland session. Is there any way to make it work in plasma wayland too.